# JAXB-2 Maven Plugin : package-info is ignored

Tags: maven, jaxb2-maven-plugin, schemagen

I have a module in my intellij IDE, which have its own maven project structure (src/main/java, src/main/test). In this project, I coded in a package JAXB classes (java).
Then in this package, I have my package-info used normally, by the schemagen goal of the org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin.
I found that it is not the case. When the XSD is generated in target output folder. My date  are still convert to string like this :

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dateSSP" type="xs:string"/>
```

I'am expecting a dateTime type like this :

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dateSSP" type="xs:dateTime"/>
```

It is clearly that my package-info.java file is ignored.
But what is strange, is that when I full build, not only the module, but the whole main project (multi module project), the generated XSD for this module is right ! I have the `dateTime` type inside XSD. But built alone, the generated XSD has a `string` type.

I don't know why.

Here the configuration (basic) of the plugin :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schemagen</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schemagen</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/java/com/allegoria/notariat/corpus/redaction/ro</source>
                        <source>src/main/java/com/allegoria/notariat/business</source>
                    </sources>
                    <!--<verbose>true</verbose>-->
                    <transformSchemas>
                        <transformSchema>
                            <uri>https://www.signatureparfiducial.fr/redaction</uri>
                            <toFile>corpus-redaction.xsd</toFile>
                        </transformSchema>
                    </transformSchemas>
                    <schemaSourceExcludeFilters>
                        <noAdapter implementation="org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.shared.filters.pattern.PatternFileFilter">
                            <patterns>
                                <pattern>Adapter\.java</pattern>
                            </patterns>
                            <patternPrefix>.*</patternPrefix>
                        </noAdapter>
                    </schemaSourceExcludeFilters>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mystake ;). Inside the package-info.java, the DateAdapter class was in another package outside of the concerned module ; it was in another module. So as I build only the module having the JAXB classes, the DateAdapter is not build and then ignored by XmlAdapters.

Thx.